# How to insert space in Pandas Column String

Tags: python, pandas

This column has bad date/time information in it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['1/25/201612:00:00AM','2/25/201712:00:00AM','3/25/201812:00:00AM',
             '4/25/201912:00:00AM','5/25/201912:00:00AM','6/25/201912:00:00AM']})
```

I tried this function below, however it produces a column of NaNs:

```
def insert_space(string, integer):
    return string[0:integer] + ' ' + string[integer:]
insert_space(df['date'], 9)
```

Desired Output example (any date format works!):

```
    date
0   1/25/2016 12:00:00AM
1   2/25/2017 12:00:00AM
2   3/25/2018 12:00:00AM
3   4/25/2019 12:00:00AM
4   5/25/2019 12:00:00AM
5   6/25/2019 12:00:00AM
```

Or

```
    date
0   1/25/2016
1   2/25/2017 
2   3/25/2018 
3   4/25/2019 
4   5/25/2019 
5   6/25/2019
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it doesnt like to work on Pandas DataFrames". Do you get an error or is the output not what you want? What output do you get?

Comment: Hi, it produces a column of NaNs

Comment: Cool. Also, how are you passing in the values from your dataframe column into the function? In cell 1 you've called your dataframe `df` with column `date`. In cell 2, you call the function with `prod['PRODUCTIONDATE']`

Comment: This was a Type-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying a function to every row of a specified column works like this:

```
df['date'].apply(lambda x: insert_space(x, 9), axis=1)
```

Note that, if working with datetime objects, you'll need to modify the function accordingly. A datetime object, such as `datetime.time()`, is not subscriptable and will raise a TypeError if you try and run it through your `insert_space` function. `str(datetime.time())` will return a string, however.

Comment: Why am I getting insert_space is not defined?

Comment: `insert_space()` was the custom function made by the person asking the question. For your own code, the lambda will take in whatever function you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%m/%d/%Y%I:%M:%S%p")
```

you can find the explanation for the `format` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, the function you provide just returns a value, which is immediately trashed.

Here is a solution using basic for loop (can be trivially converted to list comprehension or functionalized).

```
import pandas as pd

# First format
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['1/25/201612:00:00AM','2/25/201712:00:00AM','3/25/201812:00:00AM',
             '4/25/201912:00:00AM','5/25/201912:00:00AM','6/25/201912:00:00AM']})

for i in range(len(df)):
    df['date'][i] = df['date'][i][:-10] + " " + df['date'][i][-10:]

print(df)
#                     date
# 0  1/25/2016  12:00:00AM
# 1  2/25/2017  12:00:00AM
# 2  3/25/2018  12:00:00AM
# 3  4/25/2019  12:00:00AM
# 4  5/25/2019  12:00:00AM
# 5  6/25/2019  12:00:00AM

# Second format
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['1/25/201612:00:00AM','2/25/201712:00:00AM','3/25/201812:00:00AM',
             '4/25/201912:00:00AM','5/25/201912:00:00AM','6/25/201912:00:00AM']})

for i in range(len(df)):
    df['date'][i] = df['date'][i][:-10]

print(df)

#         date
# 0  1/25/2016
# 1  2/25/2017
# 2  3/25/2018
# 3  4/25/2019
# 4  5/25/2019
# 5  6/25/2019
```

UPDATE: Below are list comprehensions for the respective calls that should be far more efficient:

```
df['date'] = [v[:-10] + " " + v[-10:] for v in df['date']]
df['date'] = [v[:-10] for v in df['date']]
```